# Detect li hover and slide down child ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML, where `.subul` is hidden with `display: none`:

```
<li class="par cat-item cat-item-2">
    <a href="category/environment">
        <span class="category-text">Environment</span>
        <span class="count"><span class="count-hidden">9</span></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="subul">                                
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-40">
            <a href="category/environment/test">
                <span class="category-text">test</span>
                <span class="count">
                    <span class="count-hidden">1</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>                        
</li>
```

I want when `li.par` is hovered to slide down its child `ul` (if it has it), however I can't even seem to get it to just trigger on hover. Here's what I tried:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'li.par', function() {
    if ($(this).children("ul").length) {
        alert('code');
    }

    $(this).children("ul").slideDown();
    alert('code');
});
```

**EDIT css**

```
ul.subul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: specific reasons for event delegation?

Comment: Check if li has any height or is overlaying by any other element, causing hover event to not trigger

Comment: @Jai no specific reasons, I have this as a snippet so as to when I use ajax I don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li.par').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul.subul').slideDown();
},function(){
    $(this).children('ul.subul').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: This is good, just one thing, I noticed once (though I can't reproduce it now), it fired more than once on hover, any idea why and how to eliminate this possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This :

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'li.par', function() {
 $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', 'li.par', function() {
 $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="par cat-item cat-item-2">
    <a href="category/environment">
        <span class="category-text">Environment</span>
        <span class="count"><span class="count-hidden">9</span></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="subul" style="display:none">                                
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-40">
            <a href="category/environment/test">
                <span class="category-text">test</span>
                <span class="count"><span class="count-hidden">1</span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>                        
</li>
<li class="par cat-item cat-item-2">
    <a href="category/environment">
        <span class="category-text">Environment</span>
        <span class="count"><span class="count-hidden">10</span></span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```